# Why is this query displaying all the records?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
SELECT emp.empno , emp.ename , emp.job , emp.sal , dept.dname , dept.loc 
  FROM emp , 
       dept 
 WHERE emp.ename = 'SMITH';
```

Please tell me why this is displaying all the Records , as i am expecting only one record ?

```
     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL DNAME          LOC
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------------- -------------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            800 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            800 RESEARCH       DALLAS
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            800 SALES          CHICAGO
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            800 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            800 CREDIT
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is because your query lacks JOIN criteria to link the two tables, so the result will be a cartesian product.  Every `EMP` record will have a copy of every row in the `DEPT` table...

Your query uses ANSI-89 join syntax, which requires the criteria to be in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT e.empno, e.ename, e.job, e.sal, d.dname, d.loc 
  FROM EMP e, 
       DEPT d
 WHERE d.deptno = e.deptno
   AND e.ename = 'SMITH'
```

But it would be preferable to use the ANSI-92 format:

```
SELECT e.empno, e.ename, e.job, e.sal, d.dname, d.loc 
  FROM EMP e 
  JOIN DEPT d ON d.deptno = e.deptno
 WHERE e.ename = 'SMITH'
```

Comment: Using [ANSI syntax](http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/ansi_joins.html) makes it a little easier to remeber your `JOIN` clauses.

Answer (score 4):

You need to join the tables, not select from each. The DB doesn't know the relation to emp and dept without a join.

Try:

```
select emp.empno , emp.ename , emp.job , emp.sal , dept.dname , dept.loc from emp inner
join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno where 
emp.ename = 'SMITH';
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you have not specified how to join emp and dept, and so have a Cartesian product (all possible combinations).

Try:

```
select emp.empno , emp.ename , emp.job , emp.sal , dept.dname , dept.loc
from emp
join dept on dept.deptno = emp.deptno
where emp.ename = 'SMITH';
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of your `FROM emp , dept` clause. I expect that 'SMITH' only belongs in one department and you really need to do a JOIN instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is the result of a cross-join between these two tables (emp, dept). You are missing join condition, i.e.

```
where dept.deptno = emp.deptno and emp.ename = 'SMITH';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your `emp` and `dept` tables, as you are currently getting 1 row for each `dept` as there is no restriction applied to that table.

There is probably an `emp.deptid` column on the `emp` table, or some other joining table in the database.